# Mysterious syntax error [...] near "data" in jags

Tags: jags

When running my jags model I get the following error message

> Error parsing model file: syntax error on line 5 near "data"

In brief, what I have is two response variables (`cmax` and `cmd`) and a predictor variable (`dbh`). My idea was to estimate the correlation between `cmax` and `cmd` that is not explained by `dbh`, since the simple correlations among these variables are trivial.

Below is my code:

```
# Model input
dat = list(N = nrow(data), # number of observations
       data = as.matrix(log(data[,c("dbh","cmax","cmd")])), # log-transform variables
       T = diag(2)/1000, # var-covar matrix for non-informative priors
       r = 2, # number of variables
       m = c(0,0)) # means for non-informative priors
inits = list(P=diag(2)/1000, A=c(0,0), B=c(0,0))

# JAGS model
cat("model{

### Likelihood
for(i in 1:N){
  M[i,1:r] <- A[1:r] + B[1:r]*data[i,1]
  data[i,2:3] ~ dmnorm(M[i,1:r],P[1:r,1:r])
  }

### Priors
P[1:r,1:r] ~ dwish(T,r)
A[1:r] ~ dmnorm(m,T)
B[1:r] ~ dmnorm(m,T)

### Statistics
V <- inverse(P)
sigmaH <- sqrt(V[1,1])
sigmaW <- sqrt(V[2,2])
covHW <- V[1,2]
corHW <- covHW/(sigmaH*sigmaW)

}",
  file="Ch1/BM2.txt")

# Run JAGS
res = jags.model(file="Ch1/BM2.txt", data=dat, inits=inits, n.chains=1, 
             n.adapt=500)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, when I came to know there was another module ("data") aside from "model" in a jags model file, I began to suspect that calling my input dataframe "data" was not the most clever idea. After changing the name of this dataframe everything seems to have worked fine.